# Finding a subset of a matrix in R

Tags: r

So I have two matrices in `R` (well maybe data frames), `mat1` and `mat2` that look like this:

```
> mat1
    A  B  C
1  A1 B1 C1
2  A2 B1 C1
3  A1 B2 C1
4  A2 B2 C1
5  A1 B1 C2
6  A2 B1 C2
7  A1 B2 C2
8  A2 B2 C2
9  A1 B1 C3
10 A2 B1 C3
11 A1 B2 C3
12 A2 B2 C3

> mat2
   B  C
1 B1 C1
2 B2 C1
3 B1 C2
4 B2 C2
5 B1 C3
6 B2 C3
```

and what I would like to do is figure out which rows of `mat2` are a subset of the rows of `mat1`. For example, row 1 of `mat2` is `B1 C1` which appears in row 1 and 2 of `mat1` so the output would be 1, 1. Now, I need to go through all 12 rows of `mat1` and so, using the above matrices as my example, the output I would want would be a vector that reads something like 1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4,5,5,6,6.

I am able to accomplish this but in a looping manner that doesn't appear too efficient to me.  I want to know if there is 1) a built in command for this (maybe like subset?) and 2) if there is a more "efficient" or alternative way to do it.

Here is my code:

```
mat1 = expand.grid(list(A=c("A1","A2"),B=c("B1","B2"),C=c("C1","C2","C3")),stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
mat2 = expand.grid(list(B=c("B1","B2"),C=c("C1","C2","C3")),stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

N1 = nrow(mat1)
N2 = nrow(mat2)

idx = rep(NA,N1)
for(j in 1:N1){
    for(k in 1:N2){
        if(sum(mat2[k,]%in%mat1[j,])==length(mat2[k,])){
            idx[j] = k
        }
    }   
}


> idx
 [1] 1 1 2 2 3 3 4 4 5 5 6 6
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use this, but there is probably a more elegant way:

```
match(apply(mat1[, c("B", "C")], 1, paste0, collapse=""),
      apply(mat2[, c("B", "C")], 1, paste0, collapse=""))

[1] 1 1 2 2 3 3 4 4 5 5 6 6
```

Comment: @RustyStatistician Is it guaranteed that `mat2` is unique by row? I think this solution depends on that guarantee.

Comment: Having "data.frame"s, `match(do.call(paste, c(sep = "", mat1[names(mat2)])), do.call(paste, c(sep = "", mat2)))` should be more efficient I guess

Answer (score 3):

## Solution 1

I think this is a pretty cool solution, although it definitely trades away memory for speed, so could be a problem for very large inputs. It calls [`rep()`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/rep.html) to repeat the rows of each data.frame, one using the (default) `times` argument, one using the `each` argument, so we can get one gigantic vectorized comparison of the two data.frames:

```
r <- rep(seq_len(nrow(mat2)),nrow(mat1));
r[rowSums(mat2[r,]==mat1[rep(seq_len(nrow(mat1)),each=nrow(mat2)),names(mat2)])==ncol(mat2)];
## [1] 1 1 2 2 3 3 4 4 5 5 6 6
```

---

## Solution 2

My first instinct was to use `lapply()` and `rep()` by `sum()`, but there's probably more efficient solutions:

```
unlist(lapply(seq_len(nrow(mat2)),function(ri) rep(ri,sum(mat2[ri,1L]==mat1[,2L] & mat2[ri,2L]==mat1[,3L]))))
## [1] 1 1 2 2 3 3 4 4 5 5 6 6
```

---

Here's a generalization of the above. Now it should be able to handle any number of columns, and matches the column names from `mat2` into `mat1`:

```
unlist(lapply(seq_len(nrow(mat2)),function(ri) rep(ri,sum(Reduce(`&`,lapply(names(mat2),function(n) mat2[ri,n]==mat1[,n]))))))
## [1] 1 1 2 2 3 3 4 4 5 5 6 6
```

---

## Benchmarking

```
library(microbenchmark);
library(data.table);

bgoldst1 <- function(mat1,mat2) { r <- rep(seq_len(nrow(mat2)),nrow(mat1)); r[rowSums(mat2[r,]==mat1[rep(seq_len(nrow(mat1)),each=nrow(mat2)),names(mat2)])==ncol(mat2)]; };
bgoldst2 <- function(mat1,mat2) unlist(lapply(seq_len(nrow(mat2)),function(ri) rep(ri,sum(Reduce(`&`,lapply(names(mat2),function(n) mat2[ri,n]==mat1[,n]))))));
mtoto <- function(mat1,mat2) mat1[mat2[,id := 1 : .N], on = setdiff(names(mat2),'id')]$id; ## setdiff() only necessary to allow reusing the same data.tables
bonhomme <- function(mat1,mat2) match(apply(mat1[, names(mat2)], 1, paste0, collapse=""),apply(mat2, 1, paste0, collapse=""));
```

---

```
## OP's example data
mat1 = expand.grid(list(A=c("A1","A2"),B=c("B1","B2"),C=c("C1","C2","C3")),stringsAsFactors=FALSE);
mat2 = expand.grid(list(B=c("B1","B2"),C=c("C1","C2","C3")),stringsAsFactors=FALSE);
mat1.dt <- as.data.table(mat1);
mat2.dt <- as.data.table(mat2);

ex <- bgoldst1(mat1,mat2);
identical(ex,bgoldst2(mat1,mat2));
## [1] TRUE
identical(ex,mtoto(mat1.dt,mat2.dt));
## [1] TRUE
identical(ex,bonhomme(mat1,mat2));
## [1] TRUE

microbenchmark(bgoldst1(mat1,mat2),bgoldst2(mat1,mat2),mtoto(mat1.dt,mat2.dt),bonhomme(mat1,mat2));
## Unit: microseconds
##                     expr     min       lq      mean    median        uq      max neval
##     bgoldst1(mat1, mat2) 262.579 295.9365  320.3254  308.5525  335.7080  452.884   100
##     bgoldst2(mat1, mat2) 292.515 334.6390  358.5704  353.4555  368.2095  542.692   100
##  mtoto(mat1.dt, mat2.dt) 936.133 968.4200 1053.2665 1004.1290 1067.2080 2204.978   100
##     bonhomme(mat1, mat2) 169.779 204.8465  229.4792  218.7450  245.4735  550.390   100
```

---

```
set.seed(2L);
NC <- 10L; N1 <- 1e4L; N2 <- 1e2L;
ns <- make.unique(rep(LETTERS,len=NC));
mat1 <- setNames(nm=ns,as.data.frame(stringsAsFactors=F,lapply(ns,function(n) paste0(n,sample(1:2,N1,T)))));
repeat { mat2 <- setNames(nm=ns,as.data.frame(stringsAsFactors=F,lapply(ns,function(n) paste0(n,sample(1:2,N2,T))))); if (!anyDuplicated(mat2)) break; }; ## ensure we get unique mat2 because bonhomme's solution depends on it
mat1.dt <- as.data.table(mat1);
mat2.dt <- as.data.table(mat2);

ex <- sort(bgoldst1(mat1,mat2));
identical(ex,sort(bgoldst2(mat1,mat2)));
## [1] TRUE
identical(ex,sort(mtoto(mat1.dt,mat2.dt)));
## [1] TRUE
identical(ex,sort(na.omit(bonhomme(mat1,mat2))));
## [1] TRUE

microbenchmark(bgoldst1(mat1,mat2),bgoldst2(mat1,mat2),mtoto(mat1.dt,mat2.dt),bonhomme(mat1,mat2));
## Unit: milliseconds
##                     expr        min          lq        mean      median          uq        max neval
##     bgoldst1(mat1, mat2) 2911.58409 3124.520068 3327.642060 3343.112398 3482.843856 4032.33696   100
##     bgoldst2(mat1, mat2)  512.21419  526.099003  580.715562  567.748314  586.783137  805.94574   100
##  mtoto(mat1.dt, mat2.dt)    2.75109    3.124645    3.411087    3.271116    3.407965   12.83215   100
##     bonhomme(mat1, mat2)   37.60436   39.928438   54.498556   41.010399   42.958784  213.24218   100
```

---

Conclusion: My solutions suck.

Comment: Does this answer assume you know the column positions?  Like B and C are in the 2nd and 3rd position of mat1?  Because I want an answer that generalizes for any matrices.

Comment: @bgoldst, I agree that we should seek a solution that work for all cases but perhaps pragmatism is stronger here. don't know. nice code though !

Answer (score 0):

The following solution doesn't use column names.  It is supposed to work in all cases. It requires matrices, not dataframes.

```
mat1 = as.matrix(expand.grid(list(A=c("A1","A2"),B=c("B1","B2"),C=c("C1","C2","C3")),stringsAsFactors=FALSE))
mat2 = as.matrix(expand.grid(list(B=c("B1","B2"),C=c("C1","C2","C3")),stringsAsFactors=FALSE))
match.rows = outer(seq(nrow(mat2)), seq(nrow(mat1)), Vectorize(function(x,y)length(setdiff(mat2[x,],mat1[y,]))==0))
apply(match.rows,2,function(x)ifelse(any(x),which(x)[1],0))
```